# C : Including a source file instead of a header

Tags: c, dll, header, include

I am a beginner in *library linking* and have spent two days trying to link the `libcrypto` library to my C program on *Visual Studio 2017*.
I have had to include `applink.c` to solve my issues. But I think it is very weird to *include* something which is not a header. After searching a bit on the internet, I learnt that including a source file is something that exist but that one should avoid doing. Why then the `openssl library` does not ?

I don't think it is particularly relevant, but here is a small overview of this source file, you can find the whole source file [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ms/applink.c).

```
#define APPLINK_OPEN    18      /* formally can't be used, as flags can vary */
#define APPLINK_READ    19
#define APPLINK_WRITE   20
#define APPLINK_LSEEK   21
#define APPLINK_CLOSE   22
#define APPLINK_MAX     22      /* always same as last macro */

#ifndef APPMACROS_ONLY
# include <stdio.h>
# include <io.h>
# include <fcntl.h>

static void *app_stdin(void)
{
    return stdin;
}

static void *app_stdout(void)
{
    return stdout;
}

if (once) {
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDIN] = app_stdin;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDOUT] = app_stdout;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDERR] = app_stderr;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FPRINTF] = fprintf;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FGETS] = fgets;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FREAD] = fread;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FWRITE] = fwrite;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FSETMOD] = app_fsetmod;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FEOF] = app_feof;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FCLOSE] = fclose;

        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FOPEN] = fopen;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FSEEK] = fseek;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FTELL] = ftell;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FFLUSH] = fflush;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FERROR] = app_ferror;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_CLEARERR] = app_clearerr;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FILENO] = app_fileno;

        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_OPEN] = _open;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_READ] = _read;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_WRITE] = _write;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_LSEEK] = _lseek;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_CLOSE] = _close;

        once = 0;
}
```

What is the difference between including a header and a source file ? What are the cons and pros to do that ?

**This post isn't asking for a way to fix the link problems**

Comment: Well, openssl is not what we could call "a well programmed library"...

Comment: [You may only define a function once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) (with a few exceptions). If you were to include a source file, you would be defining each function in it *once per file that includes it*. You can get away with it if you only include the file exactly once (perhaps if you include it only in one other source file). Your problem is likely that you are not compiling that named source file or are otherwise not linking with it. Since you are using Visual Studio, you should simply add it to your project as a source file.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This is wrong, unless he includes applink.c file from his header files. Notice the 'static' keyword here.

Comment: WHich language is it? C or C++? Pick one!

Comment: @Olaf "I am assuming the answer to these questions is nearly the same in C and C++, but tell me if I am wrong." If it works the same for both C and C++, why would I ?

Comment: @Badda: Beause **it does not**. And it is not mine to explain why not, but your's to provide a not too broad question. Just that: linking is one major field of differences for C and C++ due to e.g. name mangling! Definitions and declarations and header files are another! C and C++ are **different** languages. I doubt ou would ask the same with Python and Brainfuck tags!

Comment: @Olaf I know they are different, but I also know that a few things work the same way. Thought it was the case for header including. Fixed title and tags. Also, it does not seem to me that my question is too broad.

Answer (score -1):

Including a file is just like copying the file into your C file.

This means that anything that includes the C file will have its own sort of copy of the functions in applink.c. 
You'll also notice that they're declared 'static', meaning that these copies are local to their respective files, and cannot create conflicts. They'll likely be inlined, even.

In general, this is a trade-off between binary size and compile time on one hand, and runtime speed and code simplicity on the other.

This isn't a rare thing to see, what surprises me more is that it's .c and not .h.

Comment: There is no run-time speed improvement by having multiple static copies of a function. Neither is there a code simplicity advantage. (Only `inline` has an advantage.)

Comment: less files = simpler, is it not? As for the speed, I suppose a benchmark is in order. I was under the impression it was faster because the header functions are very likely to be inlined.

Comment: Sam, I think including a .c file is bad practice. Including a .h file defining `inline` functions is OK; these will not incurr a call overhead.

Comment: The difference here is only in file extension, is it not?

Comment: @SamPagenkopf Inlining decisions are made on a on-use basis. A function can be inlined in some use cases and still exists as a function. Making them static will have no impact.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: There might be one because of CPU caching. How big depends on a *lot* of factors (and might be immeasurably low in some cases).

Comment: "less files = simpler, is it not" - that might have been true until about 10 years ago or so. It is far from being that simple nowadays.